# Universal file viewer for many files

Tags: file-management, pdf-viewer, image-viewer, cad, batch

Looking for an application that can display many files at once of varying file types. Ideally there'd be a stellar grid view of previews so users could quickly scan through them - flagging a few or reorganizing them as necessary. A few example file types, PDF, PNG, CAD, AI, PSD - the closer to "universal" the better. Not sure if there would be proprietary limitations for Adobe and others. Ideally, this would also be local software so the files don't need to be transferred. OSX and Windows compatibility preferred. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

IrfanView covers some of these but not all (https://www.irfanview.com/main_formats.htm)
https://www.irfanview.com/screenshot/big/28_menu_thumbs_view.jpg and is Windows only.

Perhaps the app called "Preview" on the Mac.

Adobe Bridge does Adobe-related ones quite well which aren't covered by others.

Comment: IrfanView will run under wine, so running it on Mac or Linux is a possibility.

Comment: "Preview" does well, but requires a bit of [extra effort](https://osxdaily.com/2013/04/06/create-contact-sheet-thumbnails-mac/) to get its grid view to be markup-able. Wondering if there are any other Mac compliant applications with that functionality baked in. Does IfranView suffer the same limitation? Some sort of section dividers would be ok too. Just need a way to communicate the fate of the related files (delete, keep, other notes).